# Rutas parametrizadas

Tags: express

Tengo que realizar un ejercicio en donde tengo que crear una ruta que apunte a "/series" y las devuelva a TODAS. El ejercicio tiene oculta la variable series ya declarada.
Mi ejercicio:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get("/series/", function(req,res){

})
```

No logor entender como acceder a todas las series.

Comment: El contexto es difuso, te recomiendo reformular tu pregunta a un ejemplo mínimo y verificable, te apoyamos en tus avances, no realizamos tareas, y si lo requieres recomendaría contrates un consultor para que te explique.

Si tu no entiendes, nosotros menos. Si haces mención de que están ocultas y al ser un método GET, supongo que está oculta en los encabezados. `req.headers.series`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te paso la respuesta y una breve explicacion.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


app.get('/series', function (req,res){
    res.send(series);
});
```

Basicamente para poder resolver el ejercicio se debe llamar a la variable "series" la cual la misma esta oculta. Esto hará que la ruta parametrizada tome todos los valores de la misma por default.

Espero que quede claro de entender.

Saludos!